# Is it Possible to Lazy Load & Type Cast the Object in Single Iteration?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am new in c# programming and have following scenario.

I am using an API which returns IEnumerable, which I want to iterate based on some object properties:

```
IEnumerable<objects> listOfObjects = filter.getItems(id);
 List<CustomObject> sortedList = new List<CustomObject>();
            foreach (CustomObject obj in listOfObjects )
            {
                obj.Load(Load.Expanded);
                sortedList.Add(obj);
            }
 foreach (CustomObject custObj in sortedList.OrderByDescending(c => c.RevisionDate))
            {
                // business logic
            }
```

I need to do all the above because I am not able to typecast the object returned in filter query. Also, the object returned from the filter query is not loaded which means if I don't execute the first foreach loop, the RevisionDate value in the second foreach will be null.

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this scenario and can these number of lines be eliminated with just 1 loop?

Comment: The way u do it is perfectly fine. It could have been simplified if it does not has the side effect of loading the obj state. I think with the current scenario it is fine.

Comment: First, you can just add `.OfType<CustomObject>()` to the end of your first line to do the casting. Secondly, if the framework you are using doesn't load the objects then use another framework.

Comment: @PeterMorris: No, you use `.Cast<CustomObject>()` to do casting. You use `OfType` to do filtering. The reason its different is because if you accidentally made `listOfObjects` have some `NotCustomObject` in it then your one will silently filter them out, thus hiding your problem, whereas the `Cast` method will throw an exception because you have the wrong objects.

Comment: @Chris If you assume you want an error then yes, if you assume you don't then no. I suppose it's a case of not enough information.

Comment: @PeterMorris: if you are saying the list *is* a list of CustomObject then `Cast` is absolutely the right way to go - why would you not want an exception when a fundamental assumption has been violated? You would only use `OfType` when you expect there to be other types that you want to filter out which is not the case here. Also we can take a hint from the OP saying he wants to **cast** the objects... ;-)

Comment: @Chris - It looks like he is using some kind of object persistence framework, where his retriever is returning a base class instead of the descendant class he wants, despite him providing the ID of an object he knows to be of that subclass. The fact that he said he is new to C# would cause me to expect him to use the word "cast" to explain his requirements, due to not knowing any alternative approaches (like filtering) despite using a "filter". If we make assumptions then either could be correct. As I said, it's a case of `not enough information` to argue for certain that either is correct.

Comment: What type is `filter`. Why is it returning the wrong type? Is there another type of filter you can use that will return the correct type?

Comment: @PeterMorris: I assumed that filter is the api code that I assumed he doesn't control but you are right, I am speculating to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the IEnumerable method `Select`.

See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx).

In short, you'll want to do something like this to eliminate the first loop:

```
List<CustomObject> sortedList = filter.getItems(id).Select<object, CustomObject>(x => 
          {
             (CustomObject)x).Load(Load.Expanded); 
             return (CustomObject)x;  
           });
```

Comment: I think your code is suffering from editing problems (your first line maybe wants to be removed?) Also there is no indication from the original post that `Load` actually returns the object. It is certainly used as if it is `void` return type.

Comment: eesh, that was ugly on my part. Corrected to remove the junk line and set the lambda to treat Load as void return.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one linq statement like this:

```
foreach (var custObj in listOfObjects
                       .Cast<CustomObject>()
                       .Select(obj => {obj.Load(); return obj;})
                       .OrderByDescending(c => c.RevisionDate))
```

Note that such usage of `Select` is usually discouraged and is not a very good practice (having something that has side effects like `obj.Load` in `Select` that is).

Answer (score 0):

Thera are several special constructs in C# libraries which were designed to handle lazy initialization. Each may have some peculiarities which may better or worse fit you needs.

First one is `System.Lazy<T>` class, than there is better performing without class overhead `System.Threading.LazyInitializer` with a bunch of static methods, and providing thread specific data `System.Threading.ThreadLocal<T>`.

Usage of `Lazy<T>` is simple:

```
// Initialize by using default Lazy<T> constructor. The 
// Orders array itself is not created yet.
Lazy<Orders> _orders = new Lazy<Orders>();

// Initialize by invoking a specific constructor on Order which
// will be used when Value property is accessed
Lazy<Orders> _orders = new Lazy<Orders>(() => new Orders(100));

// Lazy<Orders> will create the array only if displayOrders is 
// which will go through path where _orders.Value is accessed
if (displayOrders == true)
{
    DisplayOrders(_orders.Value.OrderData);
}
else
{
    // Don't waste resources getting order data.
}
```

Instead of passing lambda with constructor you can pass lambda casting your objects to `CustomObject`. If you strive for best performance avoid Linq and do it in procedural way.

Examples are from: [Lazy Initialization Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization) with comments changed by me for clarity and can be almost directly applied to your code

Comment: Perhaps you could tailor your example to the OP's situation? I am not sure at what point you convert the `IEnumerable<Object>` to your Lazy classes... Is each of his objects in the Ienumerable replaced with a lazy object or does the whole `IEnumerable` get replaced with the `Lazy`? At what point does the `obj.Load(Load.Expanded)` get called? And also I'm unclear if introducing Lazy is actually better than just calling `.Load` for each of the objects...